# Why this php code not work when tried to remove script tag?

Tags: php

Normally i use this code for remove all data inner img tag. It's work good.

```
<?PHP
$string = "<b>test</b><img src=\"https://www.google.co.th/images/nav_logo242.png\"><script>alert();</script>";
$string = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+>/", "", $string);
echo $string;
?>
```

Then i apply code for remove all data inner script tag. this is my code.

```
<?PHP
$string = "<b>test</b><img src=\"https://www.google.co.th/images/nav_logo242.png\"><script>alert();</script>";
$string = preg_replace("/<scrip[^>]+script>/", "", $string);
echo $string;
?>
```

When test code it's not remove data inner script tag. Why ?

Comment: [Don't use regexes for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: How can i do for this ?

Comment: I don't get your regex, shouldn't it be something like `<script>.*</script>`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because you're parsing `<scrip`, followed by zero or more characters other than `>`, followed by `script>`.

There is no such substring in your content. In your $string, after `<scrip` you have a `t` (which matches `[^>]+`) and then you have a `>` instead of `script>`. So, no match.

Here's what you need to do instead:

```php
$string = preg_replace("/<script.*?<\/script>/si", "", $string);
```

You cannot use `[^<]` or `[^>]` because javascript code may contain many `<` and `>` characters itself.

Here's what the above regex does:

• Search for `<script`
I intentionally did not include the closing `>` bracket here, because maybe you have some attributed in the script tag, like `<script type='text/javascript'>`

• Followed by any sequence of random characters, using [lazy evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)
Note the `.*?` instead of `.*`, this captures as *little* characters as possible to find a match, instead of as much as possible. This avoids the following problem:
`<script>something</script> other content <script>more script</script>`
Without lazy evaluation, it would remove *everything* from the first `<script>` to the last `</script>`

• Followed by `</script>` to mark the end of the script section
Note I'm escaping the slash (`\/` instead of `/`) because `/` is the regex delimiter character here. We could also have used a different character at the beginnen and end of the regex, like `#`, and then the `/` didn't have to be escaped.

• Finally, I added the `s` and `i` modifiers. `s` to make it parse multiline content. Javascript code can of course contain linebreaks, and we want `.*?` to match those as well. And `i` to make it case insensitive, because I assume you want to replace `<Script>` or `<SCRIPT>` too.